# Fullcalendar ajax before rendering view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to perform an ajax request before the fullcalendar view render is called,
 the reason for this is that i need to add html that will be generated by information given from the server to every day block. this html is not an event!!! it is appended to every day.

how will i do something like this?...

Comment: Do you want change the whole html or just want to add some content in existing html (i.e. html rendered by fullcalendar library)

Comment: just add some html

Comment: but that doesnt matter, i just need the action to perform after the request finishes @Kenny

Comment: For that purpose, you have to initialize fullcalendar view in success function callback of ajax

Comment: Kenny is correct, that's the only way to guarantee it

Comment: @Kenny i need this action to happen when every month is change.... doing this on the initialize function will only happen once...

Comment: In that case... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/ runs after the view has rendered. At that point the days are visible and available, so that would be a good time to run your function